# Access parent scope value in directive ng-switch attribute

Tags: angularjs

Why doesn't this work?

```
{{shout.user.id}} : {{$parent.me.id}} <!-- Gives: 1 : 1 -->

<div ng-switch on="shout.user.id">

     {{shout.user.id}} : {{$parent.me.id}} <!-- Gives: 1 : 1 -->

     <a class="btn btn-mini btn-danger pull-right" 
        ng-click="remove($index)" 
        ng-switch-when="$parent.me.id" <!-- THIS doesn't work!? -->
      ><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>

</div>
```

I have spaced and commented the code so it's easier to understand.

I've tried to wrap the shout.user.id and/or the $parent.me.id into curly brackets, but it didn't solve my problem.

If I hardcode the two values to 1 and 1, the ng-switch works, and the button is displayed.

$parent, in this case, is the $rootScope.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using ng-if instead. Didn't even know that existed.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the Disqus comments on the [ng-switch page](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angSwitch), it appears that Angular evaluates the value of the `ng-switch-when` attribute as a string -- it is not evaluated against a scope.

For more details, see the [Angular source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngSwitch.js), `var ngSwitchWhenDirective = ...`